# C pointers - the very basic

Tags: c, pointers

why cant I access the value of a pointer like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *num = 5;

    printf("\n%d\n", *num);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `int *num = 5;` is not the same as `int *num; *num = 5;`, but is the same as `int *num; num = 5;`. There are some small differences, though. In the first one, you initialize the pointer while in the second case, you assign.

Comment: What you're basically doing here is trying to obtain value in memory at the address `5`. Before doing that, you must be sure, that this address is belongs to your application (i.e. kernel allocated memory for your application at this address). If it isn't so, it will lead to some error like `Segmentation fault`, means your application doesn't own memory at this address and therefore can't use it. I suggest you read about [Process isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_isolation).

Comment: Awesome Cool Guy and Sam, thanks a lot. Pointers is something new in my life so I am trying to understand it at all. I really appreciated your help.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to contain the answer, or say things like "closed" or "solved".  If it is solved then accept an answer by clicking the tick-mark under the vote count for that answer.  If you want to delete the question entirely  you may do that.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are assigning an arbitrary address to the pointer, and you have no guarantee that it is valid or if it's writeable or readable by your program.

A pointer needs to point to valid memory in order to dereference it, to make a pointer point to valid memory you can declare a variable in the function and point to it's address in the stack like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int  number  = 5;
    int *pointer = &number;

    printf("%d\n", *pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the `pointer` pointer points to the address of `number` which was taken with the address of operator `&`.

Also, the `*` symbol has different uses in the above code, in the first case it is for pointer declaration, in the second case it is for pointer dereference, so this would be valid too

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int  number;
    int *pointer = &number; /* declare a pointer and point with it to `number's` address */
    /* assign a value to the pointer via dereferencing the pointer */
    *pointer = 5;
    /* check this, the value of `number` has changed */
    printf("%d\n", number);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pointer isn't dereferenceable, and not even valid. In general, a pointer is only valid if it is the address of an object, one-past-tne-end of an array, or null. A pointer is dereferenceable if it is valid and not null nor one-past-the end.

Attempting to dereference a non-derefereceable pointer results in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are accessing pointer like you mentioned. But problem is that you don't know what is at location `5` or whether it is a valid address or not.
The initialization of `m` with `5` is invalid and will invoke undefined behavior.